# Check if client is alive

Tags: multiplayer, socket

I am having client/server application and i want to detect if client is alive.

So i know that `send()` will return me `null` but it will not inform my server that client has been disconnected.

Way i came up is each N seconds send "Are you alive" message from server to client but is that good solution?

Comment: This is called a [keepalive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive). Have you observed any problems with using this approach?

Comment: No and i am doing it like that but somewhere i read it is not good idea to do it like that so wanted to ask what is other solution

Comment: Who said it was not good, and why? We can solve a problem better if we know what problem it is we're solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good solution, since it allows both sides to know that their partner is alive.

Call it "keepalive" or "hearbeat".

Added benefit, when done frequently (1/sec) you can monitor lag / ping.

Comment: Another benefit is when you try to send a heartbeat message to the "dead" client it will cause a SocketError on your end, forcing it to close. Otherwise, it may hang for a very long time.